# else and elif statements result in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

hello I am new to python coding and am wondering why whatever is inputted it results in the if statement.

```
def opnbx():
    opn = input("in frount of you is a box do you open it? ")
    if opn == "yes" or "Y" or "y" or "Yes":
        print("you open the box")
    elif opn == "no" or "No" or "N" or "n":
        print("you ignore the box and move on")
    else:
        print("please repeat...")
        opnbx()
opnbx()
```

Comment: you're not using the `or` correctly. It always enters the first condition because it always evaluates to true since `"Y"` as a boolean is considered true. If you have more than one condition in the same statement, you have to do it like this: `if opn == "yes" or opn == "y" or ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def opnbx():
    opn = input("in frount of you is a box do you open it? ")
    if opn in ("yes", "Y", "y", "Yes"):
        print("you open the box")
    elif opn in ("no", "No", "N", "n"):
        print("you ignore the box and move on")
    else:
        print("please repeat...")
        opnbx()
opnbx()
```

Comment: I'd say you probably want tuples here not list. It conveys your intent a bit more: ex. "here's a fixed set of all of the strings that I consider to be yes"

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer.